# ASP.NET - Array from Checkbox Post

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to parse posted checkbox's into an array variable in csharp. Example:

```html
 <input type="checkbox" name="ID[]" value="1" />
 <input type="checkbox" name="ID[]" value="2" />
 <input type="checkbox" name="ID[]" value="3" />
 <input type="checkbox" name="ID[]" value="4" />
```

That will be parsed from Request into something like this:

```
int[] IDs = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. You should to [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and show what has been done so far to solve it

Comment: @MegaTron I'm not expecting someone to write code.... Just looking for general direction. That's why I haven't posted my full code in the first place. 

In HTML you can post an array using the same name="ID[]" to the backend. For php I would do something like this to accept it:

$ids = $_POST["ID"];

I could then loop through the IDs. ex: 
foreach($ids as id){
  echo $id;
}

In c#, when I try to parse the HTML posted ID I get errors. There must be some common way to parse the array in c#; I couldn't find it on google so I'm asking here...

Answer (score 1):

What I was seeking:

```
string[] ids = Request.Form.GetValues("id[]");
```